# how to upload file with a new name in php

Tags: php, file, upload

am trying to upload a file with a new name. here's my code. when i use the new name i get this error::move_uploaded_file(2-text/plain09-02-22.txt): failed to open stream: No such file or directory. but when i use the actual name it upload.

```
 $path = 'temp/';
         if (isset($_FILES['$_FILES']) && !empty($_FILES['$_FILES'])) {
             $file = $_FILES['$_FILES'];
             $file_name = $_FILES['$_FILES']['name'];
             $file_tmp = $_FILES['$_FILES']['tmp_name'];
             $file_type = $_FILES['$_FILES']['type'];
           }
           $file_ext = strtolower(pathinfo($file_name,PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
          $new_filename = "$userid-".$file_type .date('d-m-y').".".$file_ext;
          $path = $path.$new_filename;
          if (move_uploaded_file($file_tmp,$path)) 
          {
           echo "upload success";
             http_response_code(200);
          }
          else {
             echo "upload failed";
             http_response_code(400);
          }
```

Comment: `$new_filename = "$userid-".$file_type .date('d-m-y').".".$file_ext;` here `$file_type` is adding `/` to path which is actually is a directory structure and not a file name.

Comment: So if you do `exit($new_filename);` you can see something like `userid-text/FileFormat-theDate.fileExtension`

Answer (score 1):

Change it to

```
$file_type = explode("/", $file_type);
$new_filename = "$userid-".$file_type[0].date('d-m-y').".".$file_ext;
```